# li:before css being ignored on IOS browsers

Tags: css, ios, iphone

Hoping someone here has seen this before. I have a site that required me to remove the default bullet points and replace them in css, on every browser and mobile device it shows up the way I've style it to aside from IOS.

I've checked safari and chrome on my iphone 6s and in the list where I replaced the bullets with a white box it's changing it to a rather large box with a black gradient.

This is how it looks on a pc/android - the bullets are orange which is the desired colour

[image]

An this is how its displaying on all IOS mobile browsers:

[image]

This is the css that I'm using for the bullets:

```
section.specificationsSection ul li:before {
        content: "\25AA";
        font-size: 37px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        line-height: 15px;
        margin-left: -.8em;
        color: #f15822;
        margin-right: 8px;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
```

I'm stumped, I've looked around to see if anyone else has seen this, asked a few designers and developers with no luck, any help is welcome! thank you.

Comment: Have you checked specific known errors for safari regarding pseudo-elements ? You could try using `position: absolute` on `:before` and `position:relative` on `li`. It might work. If not you could : not use `font-size` but use `height`. Also try using a fixed `width` instead of `auto`. Try different changes to see where the inconsistency is.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: were you able to resolve it? i faced exact same problem.

Comment: Did you find solution? I'm having the same problems too.

Answer (score 0):

iOS may be replacing the "\25AA" entity with a black square emoji? (reference: https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/521/symbols/black-small-square)

We had this issue as well. We switched to "\25FC", which looks similar to "\25AA" and avoids the huge, beveled look on iOS. We've only needed to use it in black color, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on mobile iOS devices when using "\25AA" and was able to solve it by setting the content to an empty string and then styling it into a square:

```
li::before {
content: '';
background: red;
margin-right: 12px;
height: 6px;
width: 6px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
```

}

Obviously, your particular styling needs may vary.

Answer (score 0):

safari at it again. :-/

these squares are working, but considerably larger and smaller:

small square:

```css
content: '\2B1D';
```

large square:

```css
content: '\25A0';
```

you can mitigate size with font-size, but that also effects vertical position, which can in turn be mitigated via line-height. example with the large square:

```css
content: '\25A0';
font-size: 30%;
line-height: 5;
```